# PHP: Dealing special characters with iconv

Tags: php, special-characters, iconv

I still don't understand how `iconv` works.

For instance,

```
$string = "Löic & René";
$output = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $string);
```

I get,

> Notice: iconv() [function.iconv]:
>   Detected an illegal character in input
>   string in...

`$string = "Löic";` or `$string = "René";`

I get,

Notice: `iconv() [function.iconv]:`  Detected an incomplete multibyte  character in input string in.

I get nothing with `$string = "&";`

There are two sets of different outputs I need store them in the two different columns inside the table of my database,

1. I need to convert `Löic & René` to `Loic & Rene` for clean url purposes.
2. I need to keep them as they are - `Löic & René` as `Löic & René` then only convert them with `htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES);` when displaying them on my html page.

I tried with some of the suggestions in [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) below, but still don't work,

I had a situation where I needed some characters transliterated, but the others ignored (for weird diacritics like ayn or hamza). Adding //TRANSLIT//IGNORE seemed to do the trick for me. It transliterates everything that is able to be transliterated, but then throws out stuff that can't be.

So:

```
$string = "ʿABBĀSĀBĀD";

echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $string);
// output: [nothing, and you get a notice]

echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//IGNORE', $string);
// output: ABBSBD

echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);
// output: ABBASABAD
// Yay! That's what I wanted!
```

and another,

```
Andries Seutens 07-Nov-2009 07:38
When doing transliteration, you have to make sure that your LC_COLLATE is properly set, otherwise the default POSIX will be used.

To transform "rené" into "rene" we could use the following code snippet:
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'nl_BE.utf8');

$string = 'rené';
$string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);

echo $string; // outputs rene
```

How can I actually work them out?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

This is the source file I test the code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="no-js">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<?php
$string = "Löic & René";
$output = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $string); 
?>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW: you do realize `ö` & `é` are in ISO-8859-1? Aside from the improper input charset, you might want to alter your output charset to `ASCII//TRANSLIT`.

Comment: I am so confused with these charsets...

Comment: Thanks! I had to decode some Korean characters to UTF-8 and it was a real headache - eventually, the only thing that helped was doing:
`$converted = iconv('EUC-KR', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $data);`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

And did you save your source file in UTF-8 encoding? If not (and I guess you didn't since that will produce the "incomplete multibyte character" error), then try that first.

Comment: Most probably the answer (or if the strings don't originate in the / a file, improper character set for whatever source (db,http, etc.) of data. One thing is for certain: the input isn't utf-8.

Comment: @wimvds: thanks. how do I save my source file in UTF-8 encoding? Please see my edit above - I have utf-8 in my meta <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> - is it correct?

Comment: @lauthiamkok: If you're still testing the examples above then use a good editor/IDE that allows you to select the file encoding (ie. Notepad++ on Windows, Eclipse/NetBeans on any major OS). For input from webpages you should either use meta tags or the relevant Header calls (or preferably both) and when using MySQL, make sure you open that one in UTF-8 mode as well (`SET NAMES 'utf-8'`).

Comment: @wimvds : I use Notepad++ and I just selected the file encoding - Encoding -> Encode in utf-8. Then it shows something strange in the code - $string = "LE6ic"; and I still have the same error message...

Comment: @lauthiamkok: That's normal, you should use the `Convert` options in the Encoding menu, not the `Encode` options (oh, and you should select UTF-8 without BOM) if you want to change the encoding on a file that already contains encoded characters... You can also set NP++ to default to UTF-8 encoding for new files in Settings, Preferences, New Document/Default Directory, so that you don't forget to switch the encoding to UTF-8 when editing new files.

Comment: @ wimvds: thanks for the help. I seem to get it right now. no more error messages but showing this L�ic & Ren�. so I use htmlentities($output, ENT_QUOTES); to convert them into html entities. wow I never knew about setting the encoding on the saved file can make so much difference! thank you very much.

Answer (score 28):

```
$clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', utf8_encode($s));
```

Comment: +1, `utf8_encode()` alone worked fine for me, thanks!

Comment: Note that `utf8_encode()` will only convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Comment: Great snippet. I encountered the notice in file name conversion and this solution solved brillantly my problem.