# PHP Special Characters to Normal using strtr

Tags: php, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Dealing special characters with iconv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794647/php-dealing-special-characters-with-iconv)

I am currently using the following piece of code to translate special characters like é to e. But at the moment the output is as follows.

Player Before: Touré Y.

Player After: TourA� Y.

```
$normalizeChars = array( 'é'=>'e' ); 
$player = $event->player;
echo "Player Before: $player<br />";
$playerafter = strtr($player, $normalizeChars);
echo "Player After: $playerafter";
```

Comment: Depends on your charset. `strtr` replaces byte-wise. If your input was UTF-8, but you wrote Latin-1 letters in the call, it well screw up the result.

Comment: Why is it replacing the é with A� instead of with an e? The input is from an XML Feed and by using simpleXMLElement which only uses UTF8

Comment: @alfasin how did you input the var $player though. If you just put in a special character that works for me too. But as soon as you use an XML feed with an element that contains a special e it fails.