# iconv(): Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string

Tags: php, utf-8

Hi I have seen this question asked around the traps, but so far none of the examples I have seen have helped me, when I tried them. I am getting the error **"iconv(): Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string "**, on certain input. When using the following functions together. Do you have any ideas as to how to get this error message to go away. I am attempting to convert an input string with mixed encoding to UTF8.

```
    function ConvertToUTF8($text){
         return iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), false), "UTF-8//IGNORE", $text);
    }
```

EDIT: Hi all after some looking around the following worked for us:

```
 function ConvertToUTF8($text){

    $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), false);

    if($encoding == "UTF-8")
    {
        $text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');    
    }


    $out = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), false), "UTF-8//IGNORE", $text);


    return $out;
}
```

You might be able to improve it, but it fixed our error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794647/php-dealing-special-characters-with-iconv http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631299/removing-invalid-incomplete-multibyte-characters

Comment: where is the sample string?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok so here is what worked for us.

```
function ConvertToUTF8($text){

    $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), false);

    if($encoding == "UTF-8")
    {
        $text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');    
    }


    $out = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), false), "UTF-8//IGNORE", $text);


    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

problem in your mb_detect_encoding function value return by this function is array.
use it separately.

Comment: Hi according to the PHP manual it should return a string, which part returns an array? string mb_detect_encoding ( string $str [, mixed $encoding_list = mb_detect_order() [, bool $strict = false ]] )

Comment: it return  FALSE if the encoding cannot be detected from the given string.please check it what it return.