# iconv() throw error while saving datas in database from csv file

Tags: php

Im using the below function to save csv file datas into database:

```
$name = addslashes(nl2br(iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", trim($data[0]))));
```

But it showing me the error like below

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: iconv(): Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string

Anybody please help me to solve this issue.

When i var_dump the data[0] then the result was

> string(14) "Thierry Grange" string(11) "Sergio Zini" string(17) "Sophie Desormiere" string(22) "Jacques-Benoit LE BRIS" string(11) "Roger Owens" string(17) "Jacques GUGLIELMI" string(16) "Josimar Fazolare" string(11) "Ziad Haddad" string(7) "Pu Chen" string(15) "Marco Giannuzzi" string(18) "Shilei "Bill" Chen" string(17) "Sebastien Piffard" string(14) "Wilfried Debus" string(14) "Nicolas Renaud" string(17) "Martin De Saignes" string(21) "Celine Van Vlaenderen" string(16) "Rodolfo Patricio" string(19) "Pedro Correia Pinto" string(15) "Werner Cooreman" string(17) "Martin Laudenbach"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iconv(): Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092388/iconv-detected-an-incomplete-multibyte-character-in-input-string)

Comment: Might be but i did'nt got any solution from that question and im not using function used in that question @pr1nc3

Comment: Can you var_dump the trim($data[0]) and paste it here then?

Comment: I edited my question please check it

Comment: your $data[0] is an array then. You need a loop to parse through it.

Comment: Where it's mentioned that it is an array

Comment: The var_dump printed a list of strings. It is a nested array.

Comment: I printed result inside foreach only